# turning text file with some headers into array for histogram

Tags: python, arrays

I have a file with headers containing '#' then the data which is comma separated. i.e

```
#blah
#blah
#blah 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9,10,11,12
...
```

I want to be able to skip the # and turn the data into an array (histograms over the columns). This reads it in.

```
filename = 'input.txt'
listin = []
for line in open(filename,'r'):
    li=line.strip()
    if not li.startswith("#"):
        line = line.partition('#')[0]
        #line = line.rstrip()
        listin.append(line.split(',')) 

data = numpy.asarray(listin)
SubData=data[:,0]

hist,nbins = np.histogram(SubData)

Error:
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your data to a numeric type. Your array contains strings.

```
listin.append([int(token) for token in line.split(',')])
```

Also, you need to rstrip each line to remove the line break character.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use numpy loadtxt like

```
from numpy import loadtxt
data = loadtxt("input.txt", comments="#", delimiter=",", unpack=True)
```

returns the data in column:

```
array([[  1.,   7.],
   [  2.,   8.],
   [  3.,   9.],
   [  4.,  10.],
   [  5.,  11.],
   [  6.,  12.]])
```

Use `unpack=False` to load the file in row.